# Magento 2: How to insert a custom phtml file in a static block

Tags: magento2, phtml, static-block

I need to insert a phtml file in a static block.
The Location of the file is

> app/design/frontend/Pearl/weltpixel_custom/edu/custom.phtml

I use "weltpixel_custom" as my child theme

This is the code in the static block:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="weltpixel_custom::edu/test.phtml"}}
```

I got the following error:
Invalid template file: 'weltpixel_custom::edu/test.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'magento\framework\view\element\template_0'

Do you a solution?
In Magento 1.9 it worked with this code:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="edu/test.phtml"}}
```

and following file location:

> app/design/frontend/ultimo/edu/template/edu

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Are you able to resolve it? I have added answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have called it wrong way. "weltpixel_custom" is a child theme of "weltpixel" , this is not any module so you have to move this "custom.phtml" file in any of the module like below,

> path -
> app/design/frontend/Pearl/weltpixel_custom/Magento_Catalog/edu/custom.phtml

Like above you have to move any of the other module. I have moved it in Magento_Catalog module.

After that you have to call like below

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Catalog::edu/test.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works!